# CsvReader not applying configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

I am trying to parse a CSV file, with some lines commented out with the '#' character.

I am using the CsvHelper Configuration class to set the configuration for the CsvReader. However, it does not seems to register and still read my commented lines as input.

```
var config = new Configuration
{
    Delimiter = ",",
    Comment = '#',
    Quote = '"',
    HasHeaderRecord = false,
};

using (var stream = new StreamReader(filepath))
using (var reader = new CsvReader(stream, config))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "A", reader.GetField(0)},
            { "B", reader.GetField(1)},
            { "C", reader.GetField(2).ToLower()},
            { "D", reader.GetField(3)},
            { "E", Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetField(4))},
            { "F", Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetField(5))}
        };
    }
}
```

A sample of my data in my input.csv file:

```
#fieldA,fieldB,fieldC,fieldD,fieldE,fieldF
valueA,valueB,valueC,valueD,true,false
valueA,valueB,valueC,valueD,true,false
#valueA,valueB,valueC,valueD,true,false
valueA,valueB,valueC,valueD,true,false
```

Comment: This is weird since the default configuration comment value also is `#`. Did you try to set it explicitly instead of in the constructor like `reader.Configuration.Comment = 'value'` inside the using? Same behaviour? Set one per time.

Comment: I tried that as well. I even printed out the configuration with ```Console.WriteLine(reader.Configuration.Comment);``` and it does print out ```#```

Comment: Try to put `AllowComments` in configuration to `true`.

Comment: ok that worked, but i had to take out the set comment in the configuration. That means if i override the "Comment" with the same default "#", it wont work. that seems strange to me.
```var config = new Configuration
            {
                Delimiter = ",",
                //Comment = '#',
                Quote = '"',
                HasHeaderRecord = false,
                AllowComments = true,
            };```

Comment: What if you use double quotes around `#` in Comment?

Comment: i cant as Comment only accepts char, thus need to put it in '#'. But strange thing is that if i do this ```Comment = Convert.ToChar("#")```, it works. Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: I don't really know, it probably is as it's quite weird to me. However good to know you found your way to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the below works. Or you can don't explicitly state the comment char if it is the default '#'.

```
var config = new Configuration
{
   Delimiter = ",",
   //Comment = '#' //this does not work although # is the default
   Comment = Convert.ToChar("#"),
   Quote = '"',
   HasHeaderRecord = false,
   AllowComments = true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `AllowComments = true` is the critical part.  I was able to get it to work even when I set `Comment = '#'`, but that isn't necessary since it is the default.  I wonder if cultural settings could be playing a part.

```cs
var config = new Configuration
{
    HasHeaderRecord = false,
    AllowComments = true
};

using (var stream = new StreamReader(filepath))
using (var reader = new CsvReader(stream, config))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "A", reader.GetField(0)},
            { "B", reader.GetField(1)},
            { "C", reader.GetField(2).ToLower()},
            { "D", reader.GetField(3)},
            { "E", Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetField(4))},
            { "F", Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetField(5))}
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in CsvHelper when you try to prefix your csv file with comments while having HasHeaderRecord = true. The workaround is to put your csv header as the first line in the csv, then follow it by your comment block.
Since I believe this is a non-intuitive solution, I left an issue for the CsvHelper contributors to fix:
https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/2039